# Recently created an app in Xcode and it runs fine on my computer. Sent the .app to a friend, he cannot run it

Tags: objective-c, xcode, quit

Any suggestions as to why the app will launch and quickly disappear from the dock? It's a very small app with about 80 lines of code and no outside API's, libraries, or dependencies. A simple countdown app created in about an hour.

Comment: Is your friend's computer running the same OS version? You may have to check your build settings if not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your friend run it from the Terminal window (ie ./MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApp ) and see if it prints out any helpful error message to stdout.

Comment: Hmm, in that case it may be a problem in the application's logic.  What I would do next is put a printf() (or equivalent) at the top of main(), and see if it gets printed when he runs the (recompiled) program.  If so, then your application is exiting for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Check the settings in info of the project. Check the product Name in target and project. 
And also check the "set Active target" and "set Active SDK"(Simulator).

This should work.